# How to create rounded corner BottomDrawer (aka Modal Bottom Sheet) in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

How to create rounded corner BottomDrawer (aka Modal Bottom Sheet) in new android jetpack compose.

e.g. image

[image]

Comment: Use bottom sheet in material design

Answer (score 30):

You can use the **`sheetShape`** parameter in the **`BottomSheetScaffold`** or  **`ModalBottomSheetLayout`**.

Something like:

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
        /* ... */
){}
```

[image]

Comment: When bottom sheet expanding, background does not dim. Do you know how to add it?

Comment: Can I have side margins for Rounded Corner BottomSheet?

Comment: Won't this create round edges at the bottom, too?

Answer (score 5):

In your case you need top start and top end corners rounded for that add this attribute:

```
sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = 16.dp, topStart = 16.dp)
```

In your `BottomSheetScaffold`.

Answer (score 4):

We can easily create in jetpack compose by using `ButtomDrawer` and `Surface`.

```
@Composable
fun RoundedBottomDrawer(){

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val drawerState = rememberBottomDrawerState(initialValue = BottomDrawerValue.Closed)

    BottomDrawer(
        gesturesEnabled = true, // making scrollable to fit screen
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent, // transparent background
        drawerContent = {

            Button(onClick = { scope.launch { drawerState.close() } }) {
                    Text("Close")
            }
            
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp)) // some padding

            BottomDrawerSurface()

        },
        content = {
            // outside content
            Button(onClick = { scope.launch { drawerState.open() } }) {
                    Text("Open BottomDrawer")
            }
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun BottomDrawerSurface() {
    Surface(
        color = Color.White,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp, 16.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp)
    ) {
        // your design..
    }
}
```